# repeat command until process start or timeout unix

Tags: command-line, unix, php, zip

Is there anyway to check the number of file in a directory, if the number of files is correct, say 5 files, zip the files with zip -r total.zip. If the number of files is wrong, wait 3 seconds, and check the number of files again. Keep repeating until either correct, and exit or timeout.

Is there anyway to do the case above, I have huge files that is in several part in a folder, and I want to zip it only after the file finish merging using cat command. the individual part will be remove as it is finish merging.

Comment: How do the files arrive in the directory?

Comment: using html5, files bigger than 100MB arrive in part, after all part arrived for single file, it will be merged as the original name using cat command, and then it will the part will be removed. the problem is I'm not sure when the merging process finish

Comment: would you know when the 5th file say has been completely written to the directory? It could be there - but not in complete form.

Comment: Yes, the merge command only run after the parts uploaded